# Retrieve data from a child node of a child node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve all errand names which are child nodes of a child node in my Firebase DB.

[image: I would like to retrieve all the errands]

However, I am only able to reference until the 2nd child node(the random key)
Here is my code;

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
    String r = "Errands";
    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(r);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_errands);

    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
            }
```

Kindly Assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference errandsRef = rootRef.child("Errands");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("Errands").child(key);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String Errand = ds.child("Errand").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", Errand);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
errandsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And your output will be:

```
Go to Strath
//and so on
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately its not displaying anything.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have added also and a `Log` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Your previous answer worked. I just had to attach the String Errand to a a list view.

Comment: Is there everything alright? If you still think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!